# How to create a collapsed legend for categorized symbology by size in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create a collapsed legend because the separated legend looks weird (the circles are not well aligned horizontally) as shown in *figure 2*. When I try open **Data-defined size legend**, it is showing error as showing in *Figure 1*.

The continuous field I am using have a min value of 2942 and max value 289613.

Any thoughts

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure two]